# Laravel response download file incorrectly returned as file.txt instead its intended filename

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I was migrating my laravel app to laravel 9.
Then I notice the response()->download() now returning incorrect filename and mime-type.

```php
        $headers = [
            'Content-Description' => 'File Transfer',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/zip',
        ];
        return response()
            ->download($result,'test.zip',$headers)
            ->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
```

On my browser it will returned with filename as "file.txt", but the content are correct, renaming file.txt to file.zip then the file accessible.

Additional info :

- I did run debug, and in Response::sendHeaders() every header item sent correctly includes the Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=test.zip
- before system upgrade : PHP 7.3, Laravel 7.30
- after upgrade : PHP 8.2, Laravel 9.5
- [update] this issue happened only when running on server script (php artisan serve), meanwhile running on webserver (apache) returned filename correctly

Comment: Have you tried without specifying any `$headers`? What is the original filename?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I've tried that (without $headers). Original filename something like AXX-YYYYMM-XXXXXX.zip, it's a legal document number

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue where the browser tried various optimizations.

If you want the browser to just download, without fancy special treatment based on file-type, then try something like:

```
$path = $result; // Match OP's naming.

return response()->download($path, 'my-test.zip', [
    'Content-Length' => filesize($path),
    'Content-Type' => 'application/x-msdos-program',
]);
```

> **Note** that above fakes to be the most dangerous file-type, which forces Browser-app to be extra-cautious, and just download the file (without fancy special treatment).
>
> Also, `Content-Length` may already be set by Laravel, but I wanted to be sure that download is resumeble.